# How to retrieve the HTML of an element through SeleniumWebdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, outerhtml

I'm trying to text Selenium Webdriver on Mac. I was trying to have it automatically fill the search blank of Google and search. The html for the search box is following:

```
<input class="gLFyf" maxlength="2048" name="q" type="text" jsaction="paste:puy29d" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" title="Search" value="" aria-label="Search">
```

So, I wanted to test if I can single out the above element, which corresponds to the search box. So I had it print the following to see if it did get the element:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("gLFyf")).toString
```

However, instead of printing the actual html of the above, it printed

```
[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (a8470f41df7943e813ac6f77266ed33c)] -> class name: gLFyf]]
```

Can anyone explain to me why am I not getting the element?

Comment: If you refresh the page, is the classname the same as what you have posted? I don't think it is. You might try `By.cssSelector("input[name='q']")` instead. Another issue that you will run into is that `.findElements()` returns a collection of elements. You can't do `.toString()` on a collection, you have to do it on a single element but it's not going to do what you are expecting. If you want the HTML of the element, then you want `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='q']")).getAttribute("outerHTML")`. Note the use of `.findElement()` (singular) instead of `.findElements()` (plural)

Comment: The `toString()` method won't print the HTML of a webElement; a webelement object in selenium isn't the same as a node in the DOM. Also, you're using `findElements` instead of `findElement`, so you actually just have a list of webelements, probably only containing 1 item.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question to print the *html* of the *Google Home Page Search Box* element you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  public class findElement_html {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
          System.out.println(myElement.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <input class="gsfi lst-d-f" id="lst-ib" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" title="Search" value="" aria-label="Search" aria-haspopup="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" style="border: medium none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background: transparent url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: currentcolor none medium;" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" type="text">
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you want to do? 
Do you want to check that you've found element you need?

So..

```
Webelement element = driver.findElement...
```

will throw an exception if element hasn't been found.

You can try to check the count of element found by your locator:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("gLFyf")).count
```

This will return 0 if nothing found, You can also compare it with 1 to be sure that there are no any other elements with the same classname..

```
if(driver.findElements(By.className("gLFyf")).count > 1){
     //more than one lement found
}
```